# How to enable PHP short_open_tag

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, homestead, php-shorttags

For unknown reasons my PHP sites cannot parse PHP short open tags

e.g.  `<?` rather than `<?php`. I believe this also affects the `<?=` tag, although I have not come across any issues directly relating to that in my project.

I have tried enabling `short_open_tag` in `php.ini` whilst using [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead) and [Valet](https://github.com/cpriego/valet-ubuntu) however I am still receiving parse errors.

Any help on how I can enable the use of PHP short open tags would be much appreciated as I am unable to perform a bulk find and replace.

Creating a basic php file and running `ini_get("short_open_tag")` returns 1. Which I presume means the setting is enabled? Yet a site running on valet still cannot parse shorthand tags.

**NOTE**: I do **not** want to use shorthand tags, however, this is a legacy project.

Useful information:

- **Ubuntu**: 16.04 LTS
- **PHP**: PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (CLI)    --  EDIT: (Homestead vm was running PHP 5.6)
- **Vagrant**: Vagrant 1.7.4
- **Laravel Valet**: version 1.1.16
- **Apache**: Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Comment: short_open_tag dont affect <?= since PHP 5.4. What are the parse errors from Homestead or Valet?

Comment: @leo_ap One of the parse errors I have received is the unexpected end of file, which is present when the php tag is opened using `<?` rather than `<?php`. Other times it just spits out the raw php

Comment: @RyanVincent This type of answer is never helpful. DHz obviosuly has a lagecy project on his hands and replacing the short tags might not be an option.

Comment: A silly question, but did you restart the server?

Comment: [Ryan Vincent](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3184785/ryan-vincent) if I were to run the site using a server running <php5.4 would that parse the tags and the subsequent php correctly?

Comment: Is there at least a space after the short tag? I have seen PHP not parse files because there was something like <?/*comment*/

Comment: [Pankucins](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1234502/pankucins) Yes! (... I think so) I've restarted the php & apache2 services on Ubuntu.. which I believe should do the trick?

Comment: [Jakub](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5341053/jakub-judas) Even with a space it still does not parse. specifically.. <?
}
?> 

However, once that error is fixed the rest of the PHP is output as plain text.

Comment: @RyanVincent PHP 7 is still supposed to support the short tag - only the <% tag was removed

Comment: [Ryan Vincent](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3184785/ryan-vincent) [Jakub Judas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5341053/jakub-judas) - It's starting to make more sense as to why PHP cannot parse the tags now. I'll try spinning up a VM running PHP 5.3. Thanks for the help

Comment: @DHz if you replace the offending short tag in one file with a normal tag, does the code run? It could also be some other thing that no longer parses well in php 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: This was resolved by switching to a [Scotch Box](https://box.scotch.io/) vagrant box.
Thanks all.